# Unit testing of thread synchronization (lock)

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing

I'm working on multithread app and there is part of code which sholud be run only by one thread same time. Nothing complicated. I use lock to synchronize it. It's working in life system but I would like to write unit test to check if only one thread is in the critical section. I wrote one, it was working but it stops :)
I can't figure out how to write a test it in proper way. I use NSubstitute to create mocks.

Class to test:

```
public interface IMultiThreadClass
{
    void Go();
}
public class Lock02 : IMultiThreadClass
{
    private readonly IProcessor _processor;
    private readonly string _threadName;

    private static readonly object Locker = new Object();

    public Lock02(IProcessor processor, string threadName)
    {
        _processor = processor;
        _threadName = threadName;
    }

    public void Go()
    {
        //critical section
        lock (Locker)
        {
            _processor.Process(_threadName);
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void Run_Test()
{
    //Only one thread should run Processor.Process, but we allow max 2 threads to catch locking erorrs
    SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 2);

    //Semaphore to synchronize asserts
    SemaphoreSlim synchroSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);

    IProcessor procesor = Substitute.For<IProcessor>();
    procesor.When(x => x.Process(Arg.Any<string>())).Do(y =>
    {
        //increment counter to check if method was called
        Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter);

        //release synchro semaphore
        synchroSemaphore.Release();

        //stop thread and wait for release
        semaphore.Wait();
    });

    Lock02 locker1 = new Lock02(procesor, "1");
    Lock02 locker2 = new Lock02(procesor, "2");
    Lock02 locker3 = new Lock02(procesor, "3");

    Task.Run(() => locker1.Go());
    Task.Run(() => locker2.Go());
    Task.Run(() => locker3.Go());

    //ASSERT
    //Thread.Sleep(1000);
    synchroSemaphore.Wait();
    Assert.AreEqual(1, _counter);

    semaphore.Release(1);
    synchroSemaphore.Wait();
    Assert.AreEqual(2, _counter);

    semaphore.Release(1);
    synchroSemaphore.Wait();
    Assert.AreEqual(3, _counter);

    semaphore.Release(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible (simple but not bulletproof) way is to spawn some threads/tasks in the unit test, each fetching and temporarily storing an int variable (possibly static), waiting for a bit (delay), incrementing the value and writing it back to the variable. Without thread synchronization (lock), many if not all threads will grab the same number and it will not be equal (as it should) to the number of threads/tasks.

This is **not bulletproof** since there is still a race condition making it not reproducible (the smelly code is the 50 ms delay), although it **seems** (to me) very unlikely for all treads to wait for each other in the perfect way and produce the right result.

I consider this being a smelly workaround, but it is simple and works.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task APossibleTest()
    {
        int importantNumber = 0;

        var proc = Substitute.For<IProcessor>();
        proc.WhenForAnyArgs(processor => processor.Process(Arg.Any<string>()))
            .Do(callInfo =>
            {
                int cached = importantNumber;
                // Wait for other threads to fetch the number too (if they were not synchronized).
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50));
                // This kind of incrementation will check the thread synchronization.
                // Using a thread-safe Interlocked or other here does not make sense.
                importantNumber = cached + 1;
            });

        var locker = new Locker(proc, "da horror");

        // Create 10 tasks all attempting to increment the important number.
        Task[] tasks =
            Enumerable
                .Range(0, 10)
                // You could create multiple lockers here (with their own processors).
                .Select(i => Task.Run(() => locker.Go()))
                .ToArray();
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        Assert.AreEqual(10, importantNumber, "Exactly 10 increments were expected since we have 10 tasks.");
    }
```